# " was unexpected at this time. on a cmd line block inside gradle script

Tags: batch-file, gradle, command-line

I am checking if a particular file has been used up by any other process for read/Write.
I have a build.gradle which has 2 tasks, and inside one of the task, we have a `exec`
block containing the following code:

```
exec {
            ignoreExitValue true
            executable "cmd"
            args "/c cd workspace/${project}/conf && @echo off && 2^>nul (>>${dependenciesFile} echo off) && (echo file is not locked) || (echo file is locked)"
}
```

I end up getting the following error :

```
" was unexpected at this time.
```

What could be the source of errore  here?

Comment: The first thing you need to try to understand is that there are, using your terms, two arguments here. The first is the cmd.exe `/C` option, and the second should be a single argument to that `/C` option, e.g. ```CD "workspace/${project}/conf" && (Echo=) 2>NUL 1>>"${dependenciesFile}" && (Echo file is not locked) || Echo file is locked```. To repeat, that is a single argument string, and should therefore be doublequoted when passed to `cmd.exe`. i.e. ```"CD "workspace/${project}/conf" && (Echo=) 2>NUL 1>>"${dependenciesFile}" && (Echo file is not locked) || Echo file is locked"```.